# Duplicating non primitive mesh with Python

Tags: python, mesh, scripting

I've created a mesh I want to duplicate using python with specifications for the new duplicate's coordinates. How do I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply use [**Object Duplicate Operator**](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_release/bpy.ops.object.html?highlight=duplicate#bpy.ops.object.duplicate) on the selected object(s) in *Object Mode*:

```
bpy.ops.object.duplicate()
```

By default this will create an **identical copy**, like pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in *3d View*. By passing `linked=True` to the operator, you can also create a **linked duplicate** like pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on the keyboard. This will create a new object with all of its data (like the mesh) linked to the original object.

---

To **adjust the location**, access the *Active Object* (which is the duplicate in this case) and simply overwrite the location values:

```
bpy.context.object.location = (x, y, z)
```

When duplicating **multiple objects** use `bpy.context.selected_objects` to get a list of the created duplicates afterwards. Iterate through the list and assign new position values to each object.

For more options, see this question: [Python move object on local axis](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26852/python-move-object-on-local-axis)

Comment: You shouldn't use operators like this one in a loop however, or even avoid them whenever possible: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7358/python-performance-with-blender-operators

Answer (score 20):

You can create a [copy of the Mesh datablock](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ID.html#bpy.types.ID.copy), create a new Object, position it where ever you want and attach it to the current collection/scene like this:

**Blender 2.8x**

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context
me = C.object.data # use current object's data
me_copy = me.copy()

ob = bpy.data.objects.new("Mesh Copy", me_copy)
ob.location = (1,2,3)

# Link object to the collection in context
C.collection.objects.link(ob)

# Update the view layer
C.view_layer.update()
```

**Blender 2.7x**

```
import bpy

me = bpy.context.object.data # use current object's data
me_copy = me.copy()

ob = bpy.data.objects.new("Mesh Copy", me_copy)
ob.location = (1,2,3)

scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.objects.link(ob)
scene.update()
```

You may also duplicate the original object. If you set the new object's `data` attribute to the original mesh datablock (no mesh copy created), it will be a linked duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can duplicate an object starting from Blender 2.8x:

```py
import bpy

targetObject = bpy.data.objects['TargetObjectName']
# Or you can get the target object in other ways, such as:
# targetObject = bpy.context.active_object

newObject = targetObject.copy()
newObject.data = targetObject.data.copy() # Omit if you want a linked object.

bpy.context.collection.objects.link(newObject)
```