# Set driver variable ID-block using python

Tags: python, scripting, objects, drivers

I am trying to build up a scene using python to copy objects and their drivers. The object to copy is a simple cube which has the Custom Property *prop* and a driver for its x-location. The driver consists of a Scripted Expression which references to the variable *var*, which is just the Single Property *prop* of the cube. So when I change the value of the Custom Property *prop* of the cube, I change its x-location.

To copy this cube, I wrote the following python script:

```
import bpy

def main():
    scn = bpy.context.scene
    cube = bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].objects['Cube']
    copy_loc_x = 2
    copy_obj(scn, cube, copy_loc_x)

def copy_obj(scn, obj, prop):
    # copy object and set a custom property
    copy = obj.copy()
    copy.data = obj.data.copy()
    copy['prop'] = prop
    scn.objects.link(copy)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This works perfectly to copy the object and set a new property for the copy, but the copy remains at the same x-location as the original cube. The reason for this is that the variable *var* of the copy still references to the Custom Property *prop* of the original cube.

How do I copy the cube, so that its driver variable is automatically referenced to its own Custom Property, just as <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> would do? Or, if this is not possible, how do I set the ID-block of a driver variable using python?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31348/duplicating-non-primitive-mesh-with-python

Answer (score 3):

Here is a retarget method from my [sound drivers addon](https://github.com/batFINGER/batFINGER-blender-addons).  It will change all targets that have `target.id == from_target` to `to_target`, for all drivers on the obj.

```
def retarget_driver(obj, from_target, to_target):    
    if hasattr(obj, "animation_data") and obj.animation_data is not None:
        #print("CHECKING OBJ", obj.name)
        targets = [t for d in obj.animation_data.drivers
                   for v in d.driver.variables
                   for t in v.targets
                   if t.id == from_target]

        for t in targets:
            t.id = to_target
```

Call below will change all obj targets to copy on the copy.

```
retarget_driver(copy, obj, copy)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only have one driver, and that one driver has only one variable, you can do this. after copying the object data:

```
copy.animation_data.drivers[0].driver.variables[0].targets[0].id = copy
```

If you have additional drivers and / or variables, you'll need to find better logic to access these. If you can upload a blend file, it will be easier to tell what the best method is.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy the methodology of what <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> does, use the [Duplicate Operator](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.object.html?highlight=duplicate#bpy.ops.object.duplicate) on the selected object(s) in *Object Mode*:

```
bpy.ops.object.duplicate()
```

By default this will create an **identical copy**, like pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in *3d View*. By passing `linked=True` to the operator, you can also create a **linked duplicate** like pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on the keyboard. This will create a new object with all of its data (like the mesh) linked to the original object.