# Duplicating an object in script (by name)

Tags: scripting

I want to duplicate an object (by name). In this case, tried "Cube":

```
src_obj = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
#print (src_obj) #ok, seems selected
new_obj = src_obj.ops.object.duplicate(linked=0,mode='TRANSLATION')
```

which gives me:
'Object' object has no attribute 'ops'

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Without the operator: [Duplicating non primitive mesh with Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/31353/31447)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bpy.ops` is a module directly in `bpy`, not part of any object class. It holds all registered operators. If you don't specify a region, it will always assume you want to do something in the viewport. Just replace `src_obj` with `bpy` to match the behavior of <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.
You should also make sure that the cube is the [*active* object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/126581/31447).

```
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = src_obj
scr_obj.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked=0,mode='TRANSLATION')
new_obj = bpy.context.active_object
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes sense. I can't use cube as the selected object, because it'll be cloned on the position of the actual selected object. Any workaround you would suggest?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, you can move the new object to any location and you can store as many objects as you want in variables, or even easier just store the location in a Vector()

Comment: Some context, I'm using a loop to get object positions from a given collection (several collections, several types of objects to be duplicated and positioned). For each object in collection, I need to duplicate specific object type and place them in position of each object in collection.

Comment: just pre-store them my_objects = [ob for ob in bpy.data.objects if ob pleases_me]
Then you can call them at any point for ob in my_objects:

Comment: thanks, got it working, just had to deselect before changing my location.

Comment: If you can try to avoid ops, bc. they are easy to mess up, depending on the environment (hidden objects, no VP open, wrong objects selected), try making it a habit to set loc/rot/scale rather than translating. src_obj.position = Vector((x,y,z))

Comment: Here you go: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/31353/31447